# How to i run vim on windows command line or on python

Tags: python-3.x, vim

in the tutorial, the teacher used Linux whilst i use windows which is quite different and i don't understand why he could use vim and i cant since I've followed every instruction. here's the code he used vim first_python_program.py

Comment: You could you use gvim which is available for windows.

Comment: try installing Vim exe https://www.vim.org/download.php

Comment: You can also enable windows subsystem for Linux, if you are using windows 10, to use bash and vim.

Comment: Check some other teacher, you shouldn't need a tutorial to follow the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use vim on Windows, just install it from the [official website](https://www.vim.org/download.php).

Then you can use it by opening **cmd** and typing `vim <path_to_your_file>`. (don't forget to replace `<path_to_your_file>` with your actual file).